# Need to do a registration but when register more than one user i get an error i also need to use classes and lists c#

Tags: c#, class, list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Newaccount> account = new List<Newaccount>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int selec = 0, count = 0,selec2=0;
            string quit="",sub="";
            do
            {
                Newaccount account1 = new Newaccount("", "");

                ConsoleKeyInfo letter = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("1.Create New Account");
                Console.WriteLine("2.Log In");
                selec = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (selec == 1)
                {

                    do
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
                        account1.username = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (checkusername(account1.username))
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Username already in use");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    while (checkusername(account1.username));

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
                    account1.password = Console.ReadLine();
                    account.Add(account1);


                }
                else if (selec == 2)
                {
                    do
                    {

                        int x = 0, y = 3;
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
                        account1.username = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
                        do
                        {
                            letter = Console.ReadKey();
                            if (letter.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                            {
                                account1.password = account1.password + letter.KeyChar;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                                Console.Write("*");
                                x++;
                            }
                        }
                        while (letter.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);



                        if (checklogin(account1.username, account1.password))
                        {
                            do
                            {

                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("Username and password correct");
                                Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("What do you wish to do");
                                Console.WriteLine("1.Delete account");
                                Console.WriteLine("2.Return to Menu");
                                selec2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                if (selec2 == 1)
                                {
                                    account.Remove(account1);
                                }
                                else if (selec2 >= 3 || selec2 <= 0)
                                {
                                    Console.Clear();
                                    Console.WriteLine("No such selecetion is available");
                                    Console.ReadLine();
                                }
                            }
                            while (selec2 != 1 && selec2 != 2);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username or password try again");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    while (!checklogin(account1.username, account1.password) && (count < 5));

                }
                if (count < 5)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to exit Y/N");
                    quit = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Too many incorrect tries");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            while (quit != "y" && quit != "Y" && count < 5);


        }
        static bool checkusername(string username)
        {
            int i = 0;
            bool found= false;
            if (account.Count == 0)
            {
                return found;
            }

            else
            {
                do
                {
                    if (account[i].username == username)
                    {
                        found = true;


                    }
                    i++;
                }
                while ((i < account.Count) || (!(found)));

                return found;
            }




        }
        static bool checklogin(string user, string pword)
        {
            int i = 0;
            bool found = false;
            if (account.Count == 0)
            {
                return found;
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    if (account[i].password == pword && account[i].username == user)
                    {

                        found = true;

                    }

                    i++;
                }
                while ((i < account.Count) && (!(found)));

            }
            return found;
        }


    }
}



class Newaccount
{
    public string username = "", password ="";

    public Newaccount(string username,string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password= password;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help us assist you, please don't post walls of code. Try to create the smallest piece of code that reproduces your error. That way, we can quickly diagnose the problem. You may find that in deconstructing and reducing your own code, you find the problem yourself.

Comment: What error ? where ? what did you do to get it ?

Comment: Splashing a large amount of code on a page does not make it a question. Please ask a proper question. Read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is in your checkusername method:

```
do
{
  if (account[i].username == username)
  {
     found = true;
  }
  i++;
}
while ((i < account.Count) || (!(found)));
```

specifically the line

> while ((i < account.Count) ||
>   (!(found)));

If the username does not exist then this will cause the do/while loop to carry on interating over list even though the upper range has been hit causing an IndexOutOfRange exception to be thrown.
You could change this to:

> while ((i < account.Count) &&
>   (!(found)));

but a much simpler check would be to use the Any() method provided by LINQ:

```
static bool checkusername(string username)
{
    return account.Any(u => u.username == username);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, to correct that method - `while (i < account.Count && !found)` - AND is required, not OR.